# Why output on perl eval differ between common bash output and redirection STDOUT + STDERR into file?

Tags: bash, perl

My code is:

```
  perl -e'
  use strict; use warnings;

  my $a={};

  eval{ test(); };

  sub test{
     print "11\n";
     if( $a->{aa} eq "aa"){
        print "aa\n";
     }
     else{
        print "bb\n";
     }
  }'
```

Output on Terminal is:

```
  11
  Use of uninitialized value in string eq at -e line 9.
  bb
```

If I redirect in file, the output order differ. Why?

```
  perl -e'
  ...
  ' > t.log 2>&1
```

cat t.log:

```
  Use of uninitialized value in string eq at -e line 9.
  11
  bb
```

My perl Version:

```
  This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
  (with 20 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: Output to STDERR is usually not buffered while other output is buffered. Add a `$|++;` after the use cases and all of your output will be unbuffered and the sequence will be what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler demonstration of the problem:

```
$ perl -e'print("abc\n"); warn("def\n");'
abc
def

$ perl -e'print("abc\n"); warn("def\n");' 2>&1 | cat
def
abc
```

This is due to differences in how STDOUT and STDERR are buffered.

- STDERR isn't buffered.
- STDOUT flushes its buffer when a newline is encountered if STDOUT is connected to a terminal.
- STDOUT flushes its buffer when it's full otherwise.

`$| = 1;` turns off buffering for STDOUT<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ perl -e'$| = 1; print("abc\n"); warn("def\n");' 2>&1 | cat
abc
def
```

---

1. Actually, the currently `select`ed handle, which is the one `print` writes to if no handle is specified, which is STDOUT by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an autoflush problem NO eval question.

Solution is:

```
perl -e'
use strict; 
use warnings;

$|++; # <== this autoflush print output

my $a={};
test();

sub test{ 
   print "11\n";
   if( $a->{aa} eq "aa"){
      print "aa\n";
   }
   else{
      print "bb\n";
   }
}' > t.log 2>&1
```

In some cases on terminal is the same problem:

perl -e'print("abc"); print(STDERR "def\n"); print("ghi\n");'

The only save way to get correct order, is turn on autoflush!

@dgw + ikegami ==> thank's